# Adding MIME definitions to Trinidad

Tags: trinidad-gem, embedded-tomcat-7

I'm using the trinidad gem to host my jruby application.

However, any requests for `.woff` or `.ttf` font files are met with `400 Bad Request`.

When I was jar-ing up my project with `warbler` and dumping the jar file in a regular Tomcat instance, I was able to add the MIME type definitions for those extensions in the `web.xml`.

However, I do not know how to do this for the instance of Tomcat that the trinidad gem uses, and the documentation doesn't appear to list it.  It does mention specifying a `web.xml` file to use as a default for the web applications, but that appears to be the one that's placed in the `WEB-INF` folder and the server doesn't start when I put in Tomcat's `conf/web.xml` file for it.

I've also tried adding the following lines to `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/x-font-woff", :woff
Mime::Type.register "application/octet-stream", :ttf
```

but this doesn't appear to affect the `public` folder (and I'd be surprised if it did...).

Where can I find how to do this?